# find values in a range of 2 values

Tags: perl

I have two tab-delimited tables:

```
table1

col1    col2    col3    col4
id1     chr1     1       10
id2     chr1     15      20
id3     chr1     30      35


table2

col1    col2    col3
rs1     5       chr1
rs2     11      chr1
rs3     34      chr1
rs4     35      chr1
```

I want to check if there are values in col2-table2 which are between the values in col3 & col4 - table1. If this is the case, I want to print out the corresponding value(s) of col1 & col2 into a new column of table1.

So in this example, the final results file should look like this:

```
 table output
 col1    col2   col3   col4   new_col1    
 id1     chr1    1      10     rs1:5
 id2     chr1    15     20     
 id3     chr1    30     35     rs3:34, rs4:35
```

I have several issues here:
- I guess I should work with 2 while loops.
- Normally I work with a hash if I want to store values and then see if there is a match with this value in another table. However here I have to store then 2 values, because I need to see if a value of table2 exists in a range of two values in table1.
- how to store the values in new_col1

I thought of something like this to store the ranges (I'm working in perl):

```
my @range;
while (<$table1>){
    my @cols = split (/\t/);
    $range[$_] .= "$range" for $cols[$2] .. $cols[$3]; #store the ranges
}
chop @range;
```

But how to compare then with $table2?

UPDATE: I don't only want to check if there are values in col2-table2 which are between the values in col3&col4 - table1. I also need to check if there is a match between col2-table1 and col3-table3. And if there is indeed a match, then the first thing that I described (values in col2-table which are between values in col3&col4 - table1) can be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do as you ask. It works by reading all of the information from `table2` into array of arrays `@table2`. Then `table1` is processed line by line, a fifth column calculated from the data accumulated so far, and the result printed to `STDOUT`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my @table2;
open my $fh, '<', 'table2.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
  my @columns = split;
  next if $columns[1] =~ /\D/;
  push @table2, \@columns;
}

open $fh, '<', 'table1.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
  my @columns = split;
  if ( grep /\D/, @columns[2,3] ) {
    push @columns, 'new_col1';
  }
  else {
    my @matches = grep { $_->[1] >= $columns[2] and $_->[1] <= $columns[3]  } @table2;
    push @columns, join(', ', map join(':', @$_), @matches);
  }
  print join("\t", @columns), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  new_col1
id1 ... 1 10  rs1:5
id2 ... 15  20  
id3 ... 30  35  rs3:34, rs4:35
```

Comment: why 'use 5.010' and why 'use autodie'?

Comment: `autodie` only exists in perl `5.10`. But it means anything like `open()` dies if it fails - and this is what you will normally do.

Comment: why: next if $columns[1] =~ /\D/

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention and extra match that I need to check. I will update my question

Comment: @user1987607: If you want to ask a significantly different question that can't be expressed in a comment then you should post a new question. Please don't modify your original post -- it just makes nonsense of other people's contributions.

Comment: New question posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100744/compare-values-of-different-tables-perl

Answer (score 1):

I think you're tackling this backwards. Parsing `table2` first into a hash makes the problem a lot easier. Because then you can iterate `table1` and check for any values in the range in question.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %table2;

while (<DATA>) {
    #stop reading if we've finished with table2
    last if m/^table1/;

    next unless m/^rs/;
    my ( $col1, $col2 ) = split(/\s+/);
    $table2{$col1} = $col2;
}

print Dumper \%table2;

while (<DATA>) {

    next unless m/^id/;
    chomp;
    my ( $rowid, $col2, $lower, $upper ) = split(/\s+/);
    my $newcol = "";
    foreach my $rs ( keys %table2 ) {
        if (    $table2{$rs} >= $lower
            and $table2{$rs} <= $upper )
        {
            $newcol .= " $rs:$table2{$rs}";
        }
    }
    print join( "\t", $rowid, $col2, $lower, $upper, $newcol, ), "\n";
}


__DATA__
table2
col1    col2
rs1     5   
rs2     11
rs3     34
rs4     35

table1
col1    col2    col3    col4
id1     ...     1       10
id2     ...     15      20
id3     ...     30      35
```

**output**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'rs1' => '5',
          'rs2' => '11',
          'rs4' => '35',
          'rs3' => '34'
        };
id1 ... 1 10   rs1:5
id2 ... 15  20  
id3 ... 30  35   rs4:35 rs3:34
```