# compare values of different tables perl

Tags: perl

I have two tab-delimited tables:

```
table1

col1    col2    col3    col4
id1     1       1       10
id2     1       15      20
id3     1       30      35
id4     2       10      15


table2

col1    col2    col3
rs1     5       1
rs2     11      1
rs3     34      1
rs4     35      1
```

I first want to check if there is a match between value in col3-table2 and col2-table1. If this is TRUE then I want to check if there are values in col2-table2 which are between the values in col3 & col4 - table1. If this is the case, I want to print out the corresponding value(s) of col1 & col2 into a new column of table1.

So in this example, the final results file should look like this:

```
 table output
 col1    col2   col3   col4   new_col1    
 id1     1      1      10     rs1:5
 id2     1      15     20     
 id3     1      30     35     rs3:34, rs4:35    
 id4     2      10     15
```

After opening and loading the files, I started with storing the values of table2 in arrays of arrays.

```
my @table2;
    while (<$table2>){
        next if /^\s*#/; #to skip header lines
        my @columns = split;
        next if $columns[1] =~ /\D/;
        push @table2, \@columns;
        }

while (<$table1>){
     my @columns = split;
     ... 
}
```

How can I now check if there is a match between value in col3-table2 and col2-table1. And how then to proceed with checking if there are values in col2-table2 which are between the values in col3 & col4 - table1.

Comment: please read perldoc perldsc and perllol

Comment: possible duplicate of [find values in a range of 2 values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063288/find-values-in-a-range-of-2-values)

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately,  I still have the code from last time in my notepad.

I've made a couple of updates, based on the changed requirement.  This should do what you ask. (Feeding the table data in without inlining it is left as an exercise for the reader).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %table2;

while (<DATA>) {

    #stop reading if we've finished with table2
    last if m/^table1/;

    next unless m/^rs/;
    my ( $col1, $col2, $col3 ) = split(/\s+/);
    $table2{$col1}{$col3} = $col2;
}

print "The story so far...:\n";
print Dumper \%table2;


print "table output\n";
print join( "\t", qw ( col1    col2   col3   col4   new_col1 ) ), "\n";
while (<DATA>) {
    next unless m/^id/;
    chomp;
    my ( $rowid, $col2, $lower, $upper ) = split(/\s+/);
    my $newcol = "";
    foreach my $rs ( keys %table2 ) {
        if ( defined $table2{$rs}{$col2}
            and $table2{$rs}{$col2} >= $lower
            and $table2{$rs}{$col2} <= $upper )
        {
            $newcol .= " $rs:$table2{$rs}{$col2}";
        }
    }
    print join( "\t", $rowid, $col2, $lower, $upper, $newcol, ), "\n";
}


__DATA__
table2
col1    col2    col3
rs1     5       1
rs2     11      1
rs3     34      1
rs4     35      1

table1
col1    col2    col3    col4
id1     1       1       10
id2     1       15      20
id3     1       30      35
id4     2       10      15
```

This gives output of:

```
The story so far...:
$VAR1 = {
          'rs3' => {
                     '1' => '34'
                   },
          'rs4' => {
                     '1' => '35'
                   },
          'rs2' => {
                     '1' => '11'
                   },
          'rs1' => {
                     '1' => '5'
                   }
        };

table output
col1    col2    col3    col4     new_col1
id1     1       1       10       rs1:5
id2     1       15      20  
id3     1       30      35       rs3:34 rs4:35
id4     2       10      15
```